# Participant quantity passed to Additional Participant pages

Tags: civievent, developer, online-registration

On an event registration form I need to tailor a Price Set field (ticket type) for all participant pages, based on what is selected in the Participant count on the first page.

This is doable on the first page (buyer) in a Register.extra.tpl file because the participant count field is visible on that page so the form data is accessible in JQuery, but how do we interrogate the Participant count value for all subsequent Additional Participant pages please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can answer your question, but :

If you are based upon Drupal and use Webform Integration, you can, in a webform, register several participants and build conditionnals between any fields of the webform, thus set any field value (e.g. Price) depending upon any other fields values (e.g. participant count).